# Excel: organizing identified variables in their own table

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm not trying to get super complicated with this but I'm struggling with the logic. I'm trying to organize my day-to-day time; in minutes; in three groups.

- Direct,
- Indirect,
- and Other.

I already have it set up that I type `D`,`I`, or `O` as I'm entering in my information so that my quick and dirty activity log goes as follows

```
Activity.  |   Type.  |  Start time.  |  End time.  |  Minutes.
```

I already know how to find the difference in time in mind minutes. I'm struggling on how to organize the type in a separate graph to track how many minutes of my day are direct, indirect, or other. I guess an `IF` function but I'm unsure how to write the logic. Haven't found success from that though.

Comment: Your question is unclear in what you want to achieve but to point you into the correct direction you can try the *SUMIF* function.
 `=SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)`.
In your case your **range** is the Type, **criteria** is either `D`,`I` or `O`, **sum_range** is the entire Minutes column.
Please think of what you exactly want to achieve (maybe provide an example output) and edit your question to notify people watching this question to get a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Formula is:

`=SUMIF(B2:B7, "Put D, I or O here", E2:E7)` (where column `B` is the type and column `E` is the minutes)